# How can I get the Monday's date of the previous week and Friday's date of the previous week?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-11, coldfusion-2016

I am using ColdFusion 2016.   What code is needed to get the previous Monday in the previous week and the previous Friday in the previous week?

This code below gets the previous Monday, but I want the previous Monday in the **previous** week. Same thing for Friday.

```
<cfset currentDate = Now() /> 
<cfset mostRecentMonday = dayOfWeek(currentDate) gt 1 ? dateAdd("d", 2- 
 dayOfWeek(currentDate), currentDate) : dateAdd("d", -6, currentDate) />
```

Comment: It's good to check http://cflib.org first. Usually it either has a working function or something you can adapt. Example:  [PrevOccOfDOW(day)](https://cflib.org/udf/PrevOccOfDOW). `<cfset monday = prevOccOfDow(2)>` and `<cfset friday = prevOccOfDow(6)>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to simplify your solution.

```
<cfset currentDate = Now() /> 
<cfset obj = {}>
<cfset todaydayOfWeek = dayOfWeek(currentDate)>
<cfset mondayOffset = (2-todaydayOfWeek)-7>
<cfset fridayOffset = (6-todaydayOfWeek)-7>
<cfset obj.mostRecentMonday = dateAdd("d", mondayOffset, currentDate)>
<cfset obj.mostRecentFriday = dateAdd("d", fridayOffset, currentDate)>
<cfdump var="#obj#">
```

[**DEMO**](https://trycf.com/gist/7029b86649e3c727b9f1afdd0ccb7531/acf2016?theme=monokai)

Answer (score 0):

You can get last Friday like,

```
<cfset today=dayofweek(now())>
<span>Last Friday is:</span>
<cfif today eq 7>
    <span>#dateformat(dateAdd("d",-1,now()))#</span>
<cfelse>
    <span>#dateformat(dateAdd ("d",-(1+today),now()))#</span>
</cfif>
```

Last Monday :

```
<cfif today eq 7>
   <span>#dateformat(dateAdd("d",-5,now()))#</span>
<cfelse>
   <span>#dateformat(dateAdd ("d",-(5+today),now()))#</span><br>
</cfif>
```

@user1669296, make sure, your last Monday also return wrong value.For ex. Today ( 06-sep-2018) is Monday if you run that code it's will return today date only not last Monday. So please correct it too.